# Non VBA way to copy a row, based on click, to the last row in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching online to find a way to do this but have had no luck yet.
Am looking for a way to save my Excel file as an xlsx and not an xlsm. Only because I can not get the file to work on my Android tab as an xlsm.

The only macro I am using is this:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

copySheet.Range("a14:j14").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It just copies a row and pastes it in the last blank row.

Id there a way to accomplish this without the use of VBA, so that the file can be saved as an xlsx and be accessed on an android tab?

Thank you for your time

Comment: maybe a lib for java that does just that? http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Why not separate the workbook with the macro and then another *xlsx* file which have the data.

Comment: If I separate it would i be able to use the file on an android tab and still utilize the "macros"?